# Modifying the same field in an array of objects using jq

Tags: json, jq, edit

I have an array of objects, where each object is structured as:

```
 {
   "impl": "pmdk",
   "pc_writes": 50,
   "threads": 1,
   "throughput (K tps)": 703014,
   "med_latency (ns)": 1334,
   "99_latency (ns)": 2358,
   "exec_time (s)": 14224471006
 }
```

I would like to divide the `"throughput (K tps)"` field in each object by 1000 and return the array in the same format. I tried using `map_values` in the following way:

```
map_values(."throughput (K tps)"/1000)
```

But it only returns an array of modified values as:

```
[703.014,...]
```

Instead of the entire objects, like this:

```
 [{
   "impl": "pmdk",
   "pc_writes": 50,
   "threads": 1,
   "throughput (K tps)": 703.014,
   "med_latency (ns)": 1334,
   "99_latency (ns)": 2358,
   "exec_time (s)": 14224471006
 },
 ...
 ]
```

How do I return an array of objects after dividing one of its fields by 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq '.[] | ."throughput (K tps)" |= . / 1000'
```

Should edit each `throughput (K tps)` by dividing it by 1000.

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/PTeezE-Lad)

---

Answer (score 3):

Tell `jq` to replace the value in "throughput (K tps)" by itself divided by 1000:

```
jq '.[]."throughput (K tps)" |= . / 1000' file.json
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either of `map` or `map_values` for your problem. But the problem with your attempt was you were *only* modifying the field `"throughput (K tps)"` for printing into output.

Without the `|=` update assignment operator, only the field mentioned in the expression will be printed to console.

You can use the [Update-assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) operator

```
map(."throughput (K tps)" |= . / 1000)
```

But `jq` gives you much more to do [Arithmetic update assignments](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arithmeticupdate-assignment:+=,-=,*=,/=,%25=,//=) of form `+=`, `*=` and also `/=`, so that you can do

```
map(."throughput (K tps)" /= 1000)
```